# Pandas groupby gives wrong values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have written a data frame using pandas in python that consists of numbers and strings:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [1, 5,1,5,1,5,1,5], 'col2': [20,20,40,40,20,20,40,40],\
     'col3': np.arange(1,9)*0.1,\
     'col4':['Jen','Ross','Chan','Mon','Joe','Phebe','Janice','Gunter']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The data frame looks like:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
0   1   20      0.1     Jen
1   5   20      0.2     Ross
2   1   40      0.3     Chan
3   5   40      0.4     Mon
4   1   20      0.5     Joe
5   5   20      0.6     Phoebe
6   1   40      0.7     Janice
7   5   40      0.8     Gunther
```

Using groupby, I want to find the min value of col3 for each unique pair of (x,y) where x belongs to col1 and y belongs to col2. I also need to know what is the corresponding name in col4 that results in such a min. I did:

```
df2=df.groupby(['col1','col2']).min()
print(df2)
```

I got:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4        
1       20      0.1     Jen
        40      0.3     Chan
5       20      0.2     Phoebe
        40      0.4     Gunther
```

As you see, the last two rows are wrong. Looking at the pair of (5,20) in the table, the min value is 0.2 (correctly) but appears for ross (not for Phoebe). How can I fix this?

Comment: `DataFrameGroupBy.min()` gives you the minimum of *each* non-grouping column for *each* group. It does not give you the row where a particular column is the minimum.

Comment: Where does your code specify that you're trying to get the minimum of `col3`?

Comment: `GroupBy.min` aggregates each column **independently**. The min of `['Phoebe', 'Ross']` is `'Phoebe'`. If you require a row-bound solution, see the posted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `idxmin` fix that

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].idxmin(),:]
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1    20   0.1   Jen
2     1    40   0.3  Chan
1     5    20   0.2  Ross
3     5    40   0.4   Mon
```

Or `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['col3']).drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1    20   0.1   Jen
1     5    20   0.2  Ross
2     1    40   0.3  Chan
3     5    40   0.4   Mon
```

Comment: Thanks. But, why the problem occurred? Did I miss something? Isn't groupby supposed to work correctly?

Comment: @Albert As a start, you never specified which column you wanted to get the minimum of within the groups.

Answer (score 3):

#### With `nsmallest`

IMO, use WeNYoBen's `drop_duplicates` answer.

The advantage of this answer is that it generalizes easily to take the `n` number of rows from each group.

[See `nsmallest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html)
[See `nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
pd.concat(d.nsmallest(n=1, columns=['col3']) for _, d in df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']))

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1    20   0.1   Jen
2     1    40   0.3  Chan
1     5    20   0.2  Ross
3     5    40   0.4   Mon
```